# How Do I Sort Same Columns Across Multiple Sheets?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet with 12 tabs, one for each month. They have the exact same columns, but are possibly in a different order. Eventually, I want to combine all 12 tabs into one dataset and Export a file. I know how to do everything but make sure the columns match before merging the datasets together.

Here's what I have so far:

## Import Excel File and Create Ordered Dictionary of All Sheets

```
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel("Monthly Campaign Data.xlsx", sheet_name = None, parse_dates = ["Date", "Create Date"])
```

I want to iterate this

```
sorted(sheets_dict["January"].columns)
```

and combine it with this and capitalize each column:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.title().split('\n')[-1])
    new_df = new_df.append(sheet)
    
new_df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Godel's answer should suffice. Pandas concat will do the alignment for you. You can then continue with your preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

If all the sheets have exactly the same columns, the `pd.concat()` function can align those columns and concatenate all these DataFrames.

Then you can group the DataFrame by different year, then sort each part.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using pd.concat() thinking it was a work around, but good to know it will automatically align the column names.